# React Component for splunk dont compile with error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, splunk

Im trying to follow this tutorial https://splunkui.splunk.com/Create/ComponentTutorial and i have a problem when i start the demo. The steps that im following are:

- Navigate to an empty directory of your choice and invoke Create:

```
mkdir -p ~/Code/MyTodoList && cd ~/Code/MyTodoList
npx @splunk/create
```

(I choose A monorepo with a React Component)

- Run setup and start the component in demo mode

```
yarn run setup
cd packages/react-todo-list
yarn run start:demo
```

This bring me back the following errors:

> ```
> ERROR in ../../node_modules/@splunk/splunk-utils/url.js 11:19-41
> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'querystring' in 'c:\SPLUNK\Code\MyTodoList\node_modules\@splunk\splunk-utils'
>
> BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
> This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.
>
> If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
>         - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "querystring": require.resolve("querystring-es3") }'
>         - install 'querystring-es3'
> If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
>         resolve.fallback: { "querystring": false }
> resolve 'querystring' in 'c:\SPLUNK\Code\MyTodoList\node_modules\@splunk\splunk-utils'
>   Parsed request is a module
>   using description file: c:\SPLUNK\Code\MyTodoList\node_modules\@splunk\splunk-utils\package.json
> ```
>
> (relative path: .)
> Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
> resolve as module
> c:\SPLUNK\Code\MyTodoList\node_modules@splunk\splunk-utils\node_modules
> doesn't exist or is not a directory
> c:\SPLUNK\Code\MyTodoList\node_modules@splunk\node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
> c:\SPLUNK\Code\MyTodoList\node_modules\node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
> looking for modules in c:\SPLUNK\Code\MyTodoList\node_modules
> single file module
> using description file: c:\SPLUNK\Code\MyTodoList\package.json (relative path:
> ./node_modules/querystring)
> no extension
> Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
> c:\SPLUNK\Code\MyTodoList\node_modules\querystring doesn't exist
> .wasm
> Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
> c:\SPLUNK\Code\MyTodoList\node_modules\querystring.wasm doesn't exist
> .mjs
> Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
> c:\SPLUNK\Code\MyTodoList\node_modules\querystring.mjs doesn't exist
> .js
> Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
> c:\SPLUNK\Code\MyTodoList\node_modules\querystring.js doesn't exist
> .jsx
> Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
> c:\SPLUNK\Code\MyTodoList\node_modules\querystring.jsx doesn't exist
> .ts
> Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
> c:\SPLUNK\Code\MyTodoList\node_modules\querystring.ts doesn't exist
> .tsx
> Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
> c:\SPLUNK\Code\MyTodoList\node_modules\querystring.tsx doesn't exist
> c:\SPLUNK\Code\MyTodoList\node_modules\querystring doesn't exist
> c:\SPLUNK\Code\node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
> c:\SPLUNK\node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
> c:\node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
> @ ../../node_modules/@splunk/splunk-utils/themes.js 12:11-46
> @ ./demo/demo.jsx 7:0-76 9:0-12 11:20-35

How can i handle this?

Thx in advance.

node -v
v20.11.1

npm -v
10.2.4

yarn -v
1.22.22

Comment: did you choose one of the possible fixes shown to you after `If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:`

Comment: Yes, tried that with the same result

Comment: so, even when you tried one of the fixes (which one) you get EXACTLY the same error - suggesting you haven't applied the fix correctly

Comment: I did that:
npm install querystring-es3
And this is the fallback on webpack.config.js:
const path = require('path');
const { merge: webpackMerge } = require('webpack-merge');
const baseComponentConfig = require('@splunk/webpack-configs/component.config').default;

module.exports = webpackMerge(baseComponentConfig, {
    resolve: {
        fallback: { "querystring": require.resolve("querystring-es3") }
    },
    entry: {
        ReactTodoList: path.join(__dirname, 'src/ReactTodoList.jsx'),
    },
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname),
    }
});

Comment: and the error is the same: 
ERROR in ../../node_modules/@splunk/splunk-utils/url.js 11:19-41....

Comment: I can't read more than one line of code in a comment

Comment: Dont let me format on comments

Comment: that's not what comments are for

Comment: Ok, can you follow the tutorial and see it. There are three steps, less than 3 minutes

Comment: Why? I'd just get the same error wouldn't I?